# After projecting 3D points to 2D, how to get back to 3D?

Tags: camera, linear-algebra, projection

Simple question: I used a translation and rotation matrix and camera intrinsics matrix to get a 3x4 matrix used to transform 3d points to 2d points (notated as Tform)

I transformed the point [10,-5,1] with the matrix by adding one to the end, and the new point is notated as newpoint.

Now I want to use the newpoint data to transform back to 3D space, where old_est should be equal to old.

I'm looking for the solution to plug into the XXX matrix in my code below

```
import numpy as np

Tform=np.array([[4000,0,-1600,-8000],[500,5000,868,-8000],[.5,0,.8,-8]])
old=np.array([10,-5,1,1])
newpoint=np.dot(Tform,old)
print(newpoint)

old_est=np.dot(XXX,np.append(newpoint,1))
print(old_est)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 4th row to `Tform` with the values `0 0 0 1`, i.e. the last row of an identity matrix:

```
>>> m = np.vstack(Tform, np.array([0,0,0,1]))
>>> m
array([[ 4.00e+03,  0.00e+00, -1.60e+03, -8.00e+03],
       [ 5.00e+02,  5.00e+03,  8.68e+02, -8.00e+03],
       [ 5.00e-01,  0.00e+00,  8.00e-01, -8.00e+00],
       [ 0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  0.00e+00,  1.00e+00]])
```

<sub>Note that you cannot use `append` because it also flattens the input arrays.</sub>

Observe that, when multiplied with `old`, the 4th component of the result is 1, i.e. the result is equal to `np.append(newpoint, 1)`:

```
>>> np.dot(m, old)
array([ 3.0400e+04, -2.7132e+04, -2.2000e+00,  1.0000e+00])
                                               ----------
```

It follows that `XXX` is the **inverse** of this new matrix:

```
>>> XXX = np.linalg.inv(m)
>>> np.dot(XXX, np.append(newpoint, 1))
array([10., -5.,  1.,  1.])
       -------------
```

And we get the components of `old` back.

<sub>Alternatively you can subtract the 4th column of `Tform` from `newpoint` and multiply the result with the inverse of the left 3x3 sub-matrix of `Tform`, but this is slightly fiddly so we might as well let `numpy` do more of the work :)</sub>